# Expand an element's height to the bottom of the page with TailwindCSS

Tags: css, tailwind-css

How to expand the third element to the bottom of the page ? I tested with a lot of `h-full` but then the element's height becomes the screen's height so there is a scrollbar on the right and the object is too high. I just want it to fit the rest of the page.

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="text-gray">
  
  <nav class="fixed flex shadow-md w-full bg-blue-700 p-3">
<div>
  <span class="text-xl">Navbar</span>
</div>    
  </nav>
  
  <div class="pt-16 px-2">
<div class="bg-orange-200">object1</div>
<div class="bg-red-200">object2</div>
<div class="bg-blue-200">object3</div>
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try like below:

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tailwindcss@^1.0/dist/tailwind.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="text-gray">

  <nav class="fixed flex shadow-md w-full bg-blue-700 p-3"> 
    <div>
      <span class="text-xl">Navbar</span>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div class="pt-16 px-2 h-screen flex flex-col"> <!-- 3 classes here  -->
    <div class="bg-orange-200">object1</div>
    <div class="bg-red-200">object2</div>
    <div class="bg-blue-200 flex-grow">object3</div> <!-- 1 classe here  -->
  </div>

</div>
```